# NodeJS JSON Schema Validation not working

Tags: node.js, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm a complete newbie to JSON Schema Validator, but I think is very powerful. However, I just can't validate one JSON.

This is my Schema

```
 {
  title: "Example  Schema",
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    original_image:{
      type: "object",
      properties: {
        temp_id: {type: "string"},
        url: {type: "string"},
        scale:{
          type: "object",
          properties:{
            new_width: {type: "number"},
            new_height: {type: "number"}
          },
          required:["new_width","new_height"]
        }
      },
      required:["url","temp_id","scale"]
    }
  },
  required:["image"]
}
```

And this is the actual JSON:

```
{
  "original_image": {
    "temp_id": "this is my id",
    "scale": {
      "new_width": null,
      "new_height": 329
    }
  }
}
```

So as you can see the "url" property from "original_image" is not there, but the validation returns true! And, for "new_width" I set the value to null... and again passes validation, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be working fine. The console logs errors correctly. This is my `index.js`

```
var Validator = require('jsonschema').Validator;
var v = new Validator();
var instance = {
  "original_image": {
    "temp_id": "this is my id",
    "scale": {
      "new_width": null,
      "new_height": 329
    }
  }
};
var schema = {
  title: "Example  Schema",
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    original_image:{
      type: "object",
      properties: {
        temp_id: {type: "string"},
        url: {type: "string"},
        scale:{
          type: "object",
          properties:{
            new_width: {type: "number"},
            new_height: {type: "number"}
          },
          required:["new_width","new_height"]
        }
      },
      required:["url","temp_id","scale"]
    }
  },
  required:["image"]
};
console.log(v.validate(instance, schema));
```

Comment: I was using json-schema, with the dash, but jsonschema without it appears to work well. So I guess I'll switch to "jsonschema" package, that worked!

Answer (score 1):

If you put your condition as `required:["url","temp_id","scale"]` , then, all three properties are required in the payload, but `url` seems to be missing in your payload.
    If you want `url` to be optional, then, dont put it in the required constraint.
The validator also gives back an error message.It returns missing parameters/properties if that is the case.

Comment: No, that's exactly the problem, I don't want url to be optional. The issue is that even being in required, it does not returns and error. It should because is not there, but it returns true, so the validation is wrong.